# Are the tenses used incorrectly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense

> As I work on the content of the product, he is calling the software companies.

Are the tenses used incorrectly?

Comment: They are not wrong, but the construction is unusual. Usually a more parallel structure is used: *As I am working... he is calling...* for example.

Comment: I assume you are asking because of the mix between "work" and "is calling" – but you need to clearly specify your confusion. Do not merely ask "Is this correct?" as such questions will be closed as off-topic. As our [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says: _Please don’t ask any questions about     Proofreading (for example, "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?"), unless a source of concern is clearly specified. They are out of scope for this site:_

Answer (score 2):

I believe the construction to be correct. It may be recast as one of the following:

> “As I am working ... he is calling ...”
>
> “As I work ... he calls ...”
>
> “As I am working ... he calls ...”

The meanings of all four possibilities are clear and identical in describing the state and actions of the two people.

This is not to say that “I work” is the same as “I am working”. Both may be taken as general statement describing a person’s role in life (I run, I climb, I dive, I smoke, I paint, etc) or as descriptions of a more specific time, as in the given example.

Answer (score 0):

**As I work on the content of the product, he is calling the software companies Are the tenses used incorrectly?**

**Yes**, if you rewrite the sentences like this they will work

As I **work** on the content of the product, he **calls** the software companies

As I **am working** on the content of the product, he is **calling** the software companies

The original sentence mixes **simple present** with the present continuous (also the present progressive).

> The Present progressive tense is formed by adding -ing to the base verb. [grammargeek/](https://7esl.com/author/grammargeek/)